# Asp.Net Core-Use authentication for two users with two different timspan?

Tags: asp.net-core

I put a configuration authentication for all users in the startup file,Is it possible to set a config for a specific roll with a different time?

Config :

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/LoginUser"; //"/Home/Index"
            options.LogoutPath = "/SignOut";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(43200); // 1 month
        });
```

Do I want to design a separate login form for the admin and use custom authentication?

Answer (score 2):

ExpiresUtc setting helps you to set an absolute expiration to cookie. This settings overrides ExpireTimeSpan setting value.
You could set it in your controller to set differenet timespan for differenet users

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginvm)
  { 
              .......
             var time = Time(loginvm.user);
              await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPricipal, new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(time),
                            IsPersistent = false,
                            AllowRefresh = false
                        });
                . .......
        }
    
    public double Time(User user)
            {
                double time = 0;
                if(user.Name=="J")
                {
                    time = 1;
                }
                else
               {
                    .......
               }
             
                return time;
            }
```